# Passing Variables to Start-Job

Tags: powershell, start-job

I have to be missing something incredibly simple here.  Here's a very basic script to illustrate what I'm trying:

```
$Computers = @('comp1', 'comp2')

$ScriptBlock = {
    New-Item "C:\Temp\$C.txt" -Force
}

Foreach ($C in $Computers)
{
    Start-Job -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock -ArgumentList $C
}
```

The script runs, but $C is not passed, so i just get a ".txt" file in my folder. What simple thing am I overlooking here?

Comment: `New-Item "C:\Temp\$($args[0]).txt" -Force`

Comment: Alternately, your scriptblock needs a `param($C)` line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace this:

```
$ScriptBlock = {
    New-Item "C:\Temp\$C.txt" -Force
}
```

With this:

```
$ScriptBlock = 
{
    param($C)
    New-Item "C:\Temp\$C.txt" -Force
}
```

Note: When you are passing the arguments in the argumentlist , then make sure the same number of arguments have to accepted inside the scriptblock by using param.

Comment: Something simple indeed.  Hopefully I can take this bit of knowledge and apply it to the more complicated script I'm working on.

Comment: @Tchotchke: Happy to guide you. enjoy scripting with PS